# Check time from last touch on Android

Tags: java, android, events

I want build an application that starts an event 10 seconds after the last touch. The function should turn off screen after any second when user don't use their phone (don't touch in screen). But I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Timer or TimerTask class to the do this job for you!

Start the Timer on TouchEvent!

Example:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/

Comment: thanks , but I can get event TouchEvent in my applicaton, when I exit my activity. I can get touch in screen

Answer (score 0):

You can set an *TouchListener* in your view and overide the *onTouch* method then start a timer to detect when the screen will go off and then use PowerManager to achieve screen lock.